# Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])

Tags: solidity

I have tried to verify my contract with my address and It's a ERC-20 Ropsten Test Network.
“0xee4ab34a3aa0b7d3e570df31da9f9afee9f5353b” and It just gave me a error.

Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])

It’s a Ropsten Test Network Contract and the contract is “0xf08309b47cfc7b1e88a66a913660c57388ef2bab”

I would love for someone to help me verify my contract.

Here is the contract source code

https://pastebin.com/raw/AsSn59FN

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the exact compiler version you used to compile the contract.  Go back to the compiler step and the tools you used. Inspect the setup to determine what version was used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have used a website to make the token and I'm unsure about what compiler but I will try them all.